# What's the equivalent of InStr for an array(2 dimension) in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm new to c#, if I don't explain what I need very well please tell me.
I'm reading some data from an excel file and then store the data into an array.

```
excel.Application x1app = new excel.Application();
        x1app.Visible = true;
        excel.Workbook x1workbook = x1app.Workbooks.Open(@"...");
        x1workbook.Activate();
        excel.Worksheet x1worksheet = x1workbook.Worksheets[1];
        excel.Range x1range = x1worksheet.UsedRange;
        System.Array myvalues;
        myvalues = (System.Array)x1range.Cells.Value;
```

Now I want to use equivalent  for `InStr` from `VBA` on the array, but I don't know what's the equivalent.

I have tried `Array.IndexOf(myvalue, "")`, but this work's only for one dimension array.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Are you looking for the first index of a character in a string or the first occurrence of a string in an array?

Comment: Why not good old nested for loop?

Comment: In the excel file I have a country column and every cell contains some text like this "AP Desk DE", but in every cell only the country change. I want to compare the data from the array(row, column) with a list of my country. 
But if I try do the matching between the array and my string[], it's not a perfect match. So for that when I'm looking in the array(row, column), I wanna see if it's contains the country in my list. 
If you don't understand I will try to explain in other way

Comment: I'm not sure the `System.Array` for the value of `Cells` is even correct... I'd just foreach-loop through `Cells`.

Comment: if I go by cells it take's to much time

Comment: I don't know the "old nest for loop" @DmitryBychenko , I'm new to c#.

Comment: You could look at using a lambda expression on the array maybe?  google lambda's along these lines `array.where(x=>x.indexof())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to import a range into a data structure, I think what you want is a 2d array:

```
object[,] myvalues = x1range.Cells.Value;
```

Individual values can be extracted as follows:

```
object cellValue = myvalues[3, 4];
```

If you want to loop through all cells, a foreach is easiest:

```
foreach (object o in myvalues)
{
    string myText = o == null ? null : o.ToString();
}
```

Or, if the x/y position is important, you can loop through the X/Y as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < myvalues.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < myvalues.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        object o = myvalues[i, j];
    }
}
```

Note that C# is 0-based, but in the Excel output you do want to use the 1-based references.

The `IndexOf` Function does work in C#, but not against an array like this.  If you wanted to use that, you can always cast the array to a list:

```
List<object> myList = myvalues.Cast<object>().ToList();
int found = myList.IndexOf("Foo");
```